# JavaEE best directory structure

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working on a hobby project. I use `Maven`, `SpringMVC`, `Hibernate` and `Tomcat`.

In the spring xml file I can define

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.controller" />
```

This means as far as I know that the `SpringMVC` will check this package for the controller.

But this would mean too, that all my controllers need to be in the package controller.

But what if I want to implement my webapp this way:
Lets say I have modules like profile, guest book, profile search, message.

I would prefer to have this directory structure:

```
org.profile.controller
org.profile.view
org.profile.service
org.profile.test (JUnit tests for the service classes and repository classes)
org.profile.repository

org.guestbook.controller
org.guestbook.view
org.guestbook.service
org.guestbook.test
org.guestbook.repository

org.profilesearch.controller
 ...
```

What is the best practice in the `Java EE` world for this? I would
say it is more nice to have all necessary classes in the module package itself
instead of having a package where all controllers are stored, another package where all service classes are stored, and so on.

Is there a good github `Java EE` project out there? As a newbie in `Java EE` I would like to have a good structured (maven)project as an example.

Comment: First things first, don't use XML config for a new project. Try to avoid XML entirely (no `web.xml`, no `context.xml`, no `spring-context.xml`). Second, your package naming is weird: it should be `org.domain.controller`, as Spring scans **recursively**, just set the [`@ComponentScan` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) to `org.domain`. Spring will then scan your entire project for annotated classes, if that's what you want.

Comment: So you want to tell me that xml configuration is not recommended (deprecated). And what do you thing about my presented package structure?

Comment: Yes. For a fairly long time now. With the advent of Spring Boot and [auto-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html) you can actually do most (simple) things with very minimal configuration of any kind - for example if Spring Boot detects an MVC controller it will spin up an embedded Tomcat server and activate and controllers you have - see [the documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

Comment: But how can tomcat decide which class is responsible for application bootstrap stuff if I do not have a central configuration file like the web.xml?   I mean there should something like public static void main for web apps? :-)

Comment: It's called a [`WebApplicationInitialiser`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) in Spring lingo. Since Servlet 3.0 you can use [annotated classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) to hook into web app events.

Comment: In short: please read some up to date documentation. And the tutorial I linked. Before commenting further.

Comment: Personally, I like having the configuration outside the code, so I still prefer XML. Haven't used Spring Boot yet, so might be different there. Anyway, personal choice, XML ist, afaik, still not deprecated, but fully supported.

Comment: And of course, you are talking about two different things here: Directory structure and package structure. For a directory structure, I would go with the typical maven setup ( src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/main/webapp, src/test/java, src/test/resources). Packages are not a problem, since you can put more than one in your component-scan, seperated by comma (iirc). So you can scan multiple directories, no problem there. Personally I prefer to declare my beans explicitely in the XML, but that's personal taste, again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider do you have some link or something about xml configuration being deprecated? For example [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining) says that "Spring’s [at]Configuration class support does not aim to be a 100% complete replacement for Spring XML. Some facilities such as Spring XML namespaces remain an ideal way to configure the container." so I'm having troubles believing it would be deprecated.

Comment: Yes after reading some docs I would say too that XML is not deprecated. But it is fact that in most cases you do not even need the web.xml if you work with Spring Boot. You only have to remember not to run the project in server (in eclipse), but you need to run your project with a special spring command (see docs)

Comment: @user3481997 XML is not deprecated as such (i.e. it is not being phased out). It is merely the case that JavaConfig is the recommended approach since Spring 4, and possibly even earlier. r.e. your last comment about deploying in a server - of course you can do that! You can in fact have a `Main` class that bootstraps the application standalone and a `WebApplicationInitializer` that bootstraps the application in a Servlet 3.0+ environment - this is in fact the approach described on the tutorial I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to group classes in packages based on architectural layers.
But it's up to you at the end of the day.

For example, typical structure could be like this, for application myapp:

- org.myapp.domain ->db entity classes and other domain classes
- org.myapp.repository -> dao classes etc
- org.myapp.service -> various service classes
- org.myapp.mvc -> controllers and supporting classes

Then you just do this in xml configutration file, to scan for your beans in all of your packages.

You will typically need to scan for @Repository, @Service...etc annotated classes, which all reside under root path org.myapp,and with the configuration as above they should all be found and injected into context.

Comment: Yeah thats nice too. But I would prefer to put all my architectural layers into my "module package". Means all service, mvc, repository, etc packages are under my "profile" package. The same for search, guest book, etc... Has the advantage that I have all my dependencies under ONE package.